# Auth0: Having troubles with api/v2/jobs/verification-email route

Tags: auth0

I trying to implement “resend verification email” functionality and I using `api/v2/jobs/verification-email` route. But each time I get an error `"message": "Bad audience: <my audience>"`.

I’ve read all related topics on such error and each of them contains the solution with adding
`"audience":"https://[tenant].eu.auth0.com/api/v2/"` audience.

But verification-email route doesn’t have such a parameter. So how can I handle this error?

Comment: How are you generating the JWT Access token for Management APIv2? It's possible that you are using a JWT issued for a different API/Audience?

Comment: @ShayanMemari yes, you right. My issue was because of the wrong token. I was generating it for my main API. Instead, I need to create a new one for management API.